# How to improve sse based matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, sse, simd

```
float** matrix::mult(float** matrix1){
  float** result=new float *[n];
  int i,j,k;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    result[i]=new float [n];
  }
  vect v1;
  vect v2;
  vect v3;
  vect total;
  clock_t start, end;
  start = clock();
  float result_ij=0;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){   
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
      result_ij=0;
      total.v=_mm_set1_ps(0);
      for(k=0;k<n;k=k+4){
        v1.v=_mm_set_ps(user_matrix[k][j],user_matrix[k+1][j],user_matrix[k+2][j],user_matrix[k+3][j]);
        v2.v=_mm_set_ps(matrix1[i][k],matrix1[i][k+1],matrix1[i][k+2],matrix1[i][k+3]);
        v3.v=_mm_mul_ps(v1.v,v2.v);
        total.v=_mm_add_ps(total.v,v3.v);
      }
      result[i][j]=total.a[1]+total.a[0]+total.a[2]+total.a[3];
    }
  }
  end = clock();
  cout<<(double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;
  return result;
}
```

This code is about exactly the same speed as the scalar code. I can't see why this would be so slow, it was compiled with g++ and the vect type is a union.

```
union vect {
__m128 v;    
float a[4];  
} ;
```

For the matrix as a multidimensional array, what is the fastest way to load that into the SSE register?

Comment: Well, your memory access pattern is totally non-SSE, it won't work that way. You can't read elements [k][j] and [k+1][j] and so on into one register (well, you can, but it's so slow it defeats using SSE).

Comment: You might want to try some non sse optimizations to your code first.[This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12831936/1410711) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you wanted to implement this yourself, but there's a lot of interesting code provided by Intel at:

http://www.intel.com/design/Pentiumiii/sml/index.htm

They have code for multiplying 4x4, 6x6-matrices, finding the inverse of them and other. With both versions with and without SSE, they also show some benchmarking etc